# Should I apply log transform?

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, transformation

[image]

Hsre is my skewness and kurtosis value before applying log transform. For skewness:
I use -3 < x < 3 as acceptable value and kurtosis at -10 < x < 10 as acceptable value. Since my data has a lot of negative values, I add them all with my minimum value.

```py
df_train["V6"] = df_train["V6"] - df_train["V6"].min()+0.01
df_train["V8"] = df_train["V8"] - df_train["V8"].min()+0.01
df_train["V6"] = np.log(df_train["V6"])
df_train["V8"] = np.log(df_train["V8"])
```

But my skewness and kurtosis value got worse

[image]

Should i or should i not apply log transform?

Comment: Why do you want to apply a transform in the first place?

Comment: @user2974951 because of skewness problem

Comment: And why is that an issue?

Comment: @user2974951 Im using the principle that kurtosis should be between -10 < x < 10

Comment: Why? For what purpose? These seem to be magic numbers, why 10? Why not 20?

Comment: @user2974951 well, i got it from https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/kurtosis#:~:text=Acceptable%20values%20of%20skewness%20fall,SEM%20(Brown%2C%202006).

Comment: You should mention the context of your problem, how you are going to use this data and why you think this skewness is an issue. From the source you posted `Acceptable values of skewness... and kurtosis... when utilizing SEM`, are you doing SEM? The next sentence `Values that fall above or below these ranges are suspect, but SEM is a fairly robust analytical method, so small deviations may not represent major violations of assumptions... so researchers should investigate their planned analysis to determine data screening guidelines`.